# Displaying Multiple Column Values for One Row Value

Tags: mysql

I currently have a database which houses county codes within a state and clients doing business within those counties. Sometimes, several clients will operate within the same counties. I am looking to display each county code and then that county codes associated clients as separate columns. Example would look something like the below:

```
County Code Client1 Client2 Client3
       32     1        2    
       42     3     
       43     6        8    
       44     2        8      5
       45     2
```

As of now, all I have managed to do is display it as two columns with duplicate county codes displaying different lender IDs. However, this is very manual to put it into the above format once I get it into Excel.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: You should use multiple tables for this. Something like  `Counties`, `Clients`, and `Clients_Counties`, where the last table is where you associate a county code with a clientID.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over modifying or changing the table structure or adding tables :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review, this can be done with a GROUP_CONCAT(). It puts it as a string so modification with Excel will be needed, but it's a simple solution.

```
SELECT 
COUNTY_CODE,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CLIENT_ID)
FROM CLIENT_TABLE
WHERE STATE = 'IA'
GROUP BY COUNTY_CODE
ORDER BY COUNTY_CODE;
```